# Cleaning up errors in combined C/C++ file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

When attempting to compile my C++ project in visual studio 2010, I get a bunch of errors c0254,c0259,c2061 (all relating to syntax), from visual studio's own cstdlib and cstdio files. My understanding is that this is the result of mixing C and C++. Given that I've already copied and pasted pretty liberally, how may I tell one code from the other in an effective manner? I have all the sources I copied and pasted from, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

When errors happen while compiling standard include files, it usually means that you've defined something with the same name before including the system file.  It could be a macro (those REALLY screw up parsing when there's a name conflict) or you might have defined a type with the same name as a function in the standard header, etc.

If you put `#include` instructions for standard and system include files on top, followed by `#include` for your own header files, your problems should be resolved.

Comment: On top of the file in question (a header file)? Or on top of the whole project?

Comment: @jamesson: Every file that uses `#include` should sort them in this way.

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to find the relevant file. Is there some way to inspect the error to see which file is causing it?

Comment: @jamesson: Probably.  But you haven't listed any of the errors, or the header file code which is triggering it.  I'll add an explanation to my answer.

Comment: That's the thing; I can't tell. There is one that references them, but I tried what you suggested and now I have no clue if it's still that one or another one.

Comment: @jamesson: Ah, if you look in the build output, it'll show you what file it is compiling when it encounters errors.  The error list doesn't show that information though, you need to use the output window.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10374/discussion-between-jamesson-and-ben-voigt)